# update new_status column with distinct refno by the help of sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   datetime                 refno      status      final_status
----------------------------------------------------------------
   2016-12-01 10:00:00      123456     hold
   2016-12-02 11:10:00      123456     delivered 
   2016-12-01 10:00:00      654321     hold
   2016-12-02 12:20:00      654321     delivered 
   2016-12-01 10:00:00      111111     hold
   2016-12-01 01:00:00      222222     hold
```

I want to distinct refno if Refno is delivered then new_status column will update with delivered otherwise update with hold

like this type:-

output:-

```
   datetime                 refno      status      final_status
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
   2016-12-01 10:00:00      123456     hold        delivered 
   2016-12-01 10:00:00      654321     hold        delivered 
   2016-12-01 10:00:00      111111     hold        hold
   2016-12-01 01:00:00      222222     hold        hold
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are going to be only `hold` and `delivered` values in the `status` column below will work for you.

```
select
  min(datetime),
  refno,
  max(status) status,
  min(status) final_status
from
  my_table
group by
  refno;
```